# Allowing Only Logged In Users To See A Page

Tags: php, authentication, yii, session-variables

After a user is logged in, I redirect them to a page which is the user area.
Now if someone has the url but isn't logged-in (guest), then they shouldn't
be able to access that page. Currently I put a condition on top of my page
that checks if the user is logged-in, I say if the user is guest then redirect
them to the home page. Is that how I should do it in Yii or there is a better
way of doing it ? I basically tried to mimic the way I used to do it in pure
PHP before.

Comment: you should post the code you use to bother verify a user is logged in, and also how the page checks for that

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth

Comment: Quite easy with Yii and access control filter : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#access-control-filter

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The way I do it:

In the xController, at actionY, i check if the user is guest or logged in.

If the user is a guest, redirect him to site/index

Else, render the page.

Comment: Yii has a built-in feature for this, you should read this : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#access-control-filter

Comment: yes, true, but it is better to know how to do it manually also

Comment: don't just vote with -s, if you know something better, don't just comment, post IT!